# Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) during combining csvs into a single dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, compiler-errors, data-analysis

I am having files "acc00001.csv", "acc00002.csv"........."acc02803.csv" in

```
folder <- "D:/bearing rul project/Learning_set/Bearing1_1/"
```

file_list is the list which contains all the files

```
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")
```

I want to import them in a single dataframe.
I used the following code

```
data1 <- 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(file_list, function(x) read.csv(paste(folder, x, sep=''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

But it is giving an error

Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

I tried the following

```
for (i in 2:length(file_list)){
  names(file_list[[i]])<- names(file_list[[i-1]])
}
```

and also checked for following

```
identical(names(file_list[[2]]), names(file_list[[2803]]))
```

It is giving True for every iteration. please help......

Comment: Do you have those files in the folder?  What is there in the `file_list` ?try  `files <- paste0(folder, c("acc00001.csv", "acc00002.csv")); lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun sorry for inconvenience. I edited the question. Yes file-list contains all the files.  your line gives following error **Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection**